# MySQL use subquery from FROM in WHERE

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a question about MySQL. My script looks like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (subQuery) AS q1
WHERE
    (SELECT something
     FROM q1
     WHERE id = q1.id-1) = x;
```

My problem is that in the last subquery the table `q1` is unknown. How can I solve this?

Comment: As long as you are including "something" in the subquery, you should just be able to do `WHERE q1.something = x`....wait, what?! What do you think `FROM q1 WHERE id = q1.id-1` is going to do?

Comment: The table from the First subquery has a colum called id. I Need to Check a Value in The Row befor the Current one

Comment: You  may have to resort to a temporary table.

Comment: Ah, no, you can't do that. See answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare rows in the results. The best you could do is duplicate the subquery, call it q1b for example, and join it to q1 `on q1.id - 1 = q1b.id`; then in the where have something like `q1b.something = x` *(though that can be in the ON as well)*

There is also some possibilities with temp tables; but you still need the two joins, or maybe a correlated subquery in the where would work. ... if stored in a true TEMPORARY table, not just some "dummy" table you drop after, you'll need two copies. You can't use the same TEMPORARY table twice in the same query.

Comment: Yeah Thank you Very much . i sloved it with 2 Temp Tabels befor but i get told it is to complicated